# WP disable plugin on specific page(s)

Tags: wordpress, plugins, lightbox

I would like to know how to disable the Easy-Fancybox plugin from opening the images on a specific page. The images on the page below are instead using a filmstrip lightbox from a purchased plugin called 'Photo Gallery'. I require the Easy-Fancybox plugin elsewhere around the website though.

http://181.224.157.231/~alcappar/collections/summer-2014/

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay I found another plugin called 'Plugin Organizer' which lets you select an action per plugin. It worked perfectly. I hope this is useful to some other people out there.

https://wordpress.org/plugins/plugin-organizer/

Answer (score -1):

Try this plugin https://wordpress.org/plugins/wp-optimize-it/ it will let you disable specific plugins on specific pages

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference. Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes